# Shouldn't 'this' inside a function point to the object itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, prototype

Thanks guys, this turned out to be my own confusion about the grammar of ES6 class.

But I asked this question because I encountered the following problem.

I was learning React and I have the following snippet of code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render() {
    // console.log(this);
    return <div>
            <input
                onChange={ this.onInputChange }
            />
        </div>;
    }

    onInputChange(event) {
        console.log(this);
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Fairly simple, this code will generate an input component and when things within it changes, we log out 'this'.

However, this code will generate 'undefined' all the time.

As I know that 'this' within the object child function should point to object itself, **why** this is happening?

By the way, the main js file looks like this.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';

import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';

const API_KEY = 'AIzaSyCdAXs0YXxqGUKjb4sZsmsF_hHq_f3PJmY';

const App = () => {
    return (
            <div>
            <SearchBar />
            </div>
            );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

And the html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

where bundle.js is the output react script with bable.

Comment: Because you are using prototypical inheritance

Comment: The value of `this` within a function depends on how that function was called. In over-simplified terms, if you call a function using "dot" notation like `tester.hello()` then within the function `this` will be set to the object to the left of the `.` - in your case that is `tester`. This is a duplicate, but i think [the MDN page on `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) explains it better than the other question's accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

`this` keyword points to object that named test because of the `prototype`. hello function is not a seperated function from test object.

If you ask why use prototype?

Using the prototype makes for faster object creation, since that function does not have to be re-created each time a new object is created.

Comment: Thanks for helping, it turned out I misunderstand the prototype chain rule.